# start a SAML SSO transaction from the identity provider

Tags: security, web, single-sign-on, saml

Consider this schema https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation.
User will go to the service provider and from there redirected to the identity provider.
But, In my system the user is on the Identity provider to begin with, and presses a link to go to the Service Provider.
So, **My question** is there a problem with skipping step 1 to 4 and start directly from 5 (Generate a SAML "response" and send it to the Service Provider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called Unsolicited Responses in the SAML specs. Also called IDP initiated SSO.

It depends on the IPD and SP you are using if this is supported or not. Generally I recommend against using this. It breaks interoperability between products, opens up for XSRF attacs

Comment: >It breaks interoperability between products, opens up for XSRF attacs

Stefan, I rarely disagree with you... But I'm going to here. It shouldn't do either of those. Spec-compliant systems shouldn't have any interoperability issues here (this is why the protocol exists - to define a standard way of doing things). And any SP that doesn't sanity-check the RelayState that it gets passed from an IdP to ensure that it's a "valid" place for them to redirect to is quite foolish.

Comment: Agree to dissagree. I would recomend you reading this discution on the subject. Very interesting. http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/users/2014-December/018765.html

Comment: I don't agree with Scott on this either, apparently. Seem shib doesn't scrub its unsolicited responses for sanity. Rather silly.